# Drive path not retained in softwear memory after reboot

Tags: filesystem, paths

Question rephrased to better fit my situation at the time of asking:

After rebooting my computer; all memory of recent file use by software programmes accessing files upon my second hard disk, are lost; How can I stop this loss of information?

Comment: Yes it looks as though both questions are related; seems to be a certain amount of ambiguity, for one new to ubuntu, as to what a mounted drive is.
Is the drive appearing due to the Gnome automount and thus is not mounted by the system at start up.
If I can "see" the problem it is easer to grasp and then over come; I would like to learn the ropes rather than install a GUI for the task.

Comment: Did you read [binW's answer](/a/19118)? It refers to the manipulation of a system configuration file `/etc/fstab` and links to a [description in the Ubuntu Wiki](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: Yes, just investigating now; modifying manually created a conflict whilst mounting the disk, probably caused by my having also played with a utility that I have found that is already installed called "Disks"; I think installed by default with Ubuntu, that writes to the same file when we deactivate the automatic mount function; This may well have been the cause of the conflict. I am still investigating that. The inconsistent path problem has been solved and the disk is now in the /mnt folder rather than in the /media folder.
Should I add my findings to the initial question and delete this one?